# Python MySQL insertion error 1064

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-error-1064

I'm writing a programme that will extract data from a text file and input that data in a MySQL database and I'm having a small problem with the insertion. Every time I run the programme, it seems to add an additional ' into the first data entry, i.e. I get ''12 Points Jazz Festival - 5/3/2008-8/3/2008', instead of '12 Points Jazz Festival - 5/3/2008-8/3/2008',.

When I put the data into a print method, the extra ' is not present. I've been searching this site and others for the last few days to find if anyone else has had this problem but I haven't found any solutions.

```
     def event_single(self, title, description, startDate, endDate, location, url, event, contact, category):

    with self.con:
        self.cur.execute("""INSERT IGNORE INTO events_Event(title, description, startdate, enddate, """
                         """location, url, event, contact, category_1) value %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s""",
                        (title, description, startDate, endDate, location, url, event, contact, category))

        self.con.commit()


    self.con.close()
```

This is the error I get

```
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''12 Points Jazz Festival - 5/3/2008-8/3/2008', '', '5/3/2008', '8/3/2008', Proj' at line 1")
```

Any input would be most appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I think it should be values and not value. And need a pair of bracket around values like values (%s,%s.....)

Comment: I'm not sure if this fixes the problem as I'm now getting another error with a foreign key. Value and Values seem to be interchangeable  but the brackets seem to cause the new error. I'll look into fixing this new error. Thanks for your answer.